# Getting data from xml with xpath web api c#

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, xpath

i start saying im working on a async web api application using C# and .net core 5.

This application need to read a XML file, giving the "ok" response (async mode), and give me back the values, for insert them into a DB.

I wrote an algorithm like this to read a list of nodes but i dont know why it dont iterate correctly through the nodeList...

```
public class LetturaXml
{
    public List<InsertClassDTO> xmlToList(InputDTO input)
    {
        List<InsertClassDTO> list = new List<AnnuncioAutoDTO>();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(input.filePath);

        XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//ITEM[@CATEGORYID=10]");

        foreach (XmlNode item in nodeList)
        {
            //.... tranfert into DTO, then into list, and finally insert into DB for every iteration
        }
    }
}
```

thanks all for the help !

P.S.

xml example:

```html
<ITEM ID="5331" CITYID="7" CATEGORYID="10" LASTUPDATE="2021-05-14" EXPIRED="0">
      <ISTAT>000</ISTAT>
      <TITLE><![CDATA[title]]></TITLE>
      <TEXT>
           <![CDATA[text]]>
      </TEXT>
      <EMAIL>@hotmail.it</EMAIL>
      <ATTRIBUTELIST>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
          <ATTRID>prezzo</ATTRID>
          <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
          <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[3400]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
          <ATTRID>telagenzia</ATTRID>
          <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
          <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[33333333333]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
          <ATTRID>contattotelefonico</ATTRID>
          <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
          <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[33333333333]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
          <ATTRID>2</ATTRID>
          <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
          <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>4</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>indirizzoagenzia</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>comuneagenzia</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>capagenzia</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>inserzionistaauto</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>tipocomprovendo</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>inserzionistaauto</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>marca</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>modello</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>condizioneveicolo</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>km</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>immatricolazione</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      <ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRID>alimentazione</ATTRID>
        <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
        <ATTRVAL></ATTRVAL>
      </ATTRIBUTE>
      </ATTRIBUTELIST>
      <IMAGELIST>
          <IMGFILE><![CDATA[exampleLink.jpg]]></IMGFILE>
      </IMAGELIST>
  </ITEM>
```

Comment: If you run `doc.SelectNodes("//ITEM[@CATEGORYID=10]")` in quick watch, what does this display? Also can you add the XML data for `input.filePath` to the question?

Comment: the selectNodes display what i want, the items who match the xpath exp.
meanwhile i put the example of an item i get from the method at the start of the post

Comment: i just need to take some (not all) data (for example CDATA or attributes) from this type of node with the foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will be enough of a starting point for you to finish off:

```
var xml = @"
<ITEM ID=""5331"" CITYID=""7"" CATEGORYID=""10"" LASTUPDATE=""2021-05-14"" EXPIRED=""0"">
        <ISTAT>000</ISTAT>
        <TITLE><![CDATA[title]]></TITLE>
        <TEXT>
            <![CDATA[text]]>
        </TEXT>
        <EMAIL>@hotmail.it</EMAIL>
        <ATTRIBUTELIST>
        <ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRID>prezzo</ATTRID>
            <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
            <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[3400]]></ATTRVAL>
        </ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRID>telagenzia</ATTRID>
            <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
            <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[33333333333]]></ATTRVAL>
        </ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRID>contattotelefonico</ATTRID>
            <ATTRNAME></ATTRNAME>
            <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[33333333333]]></ATTRVAL>
        </ATTRIBUTE>
        <ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRID>2</ATTRID>
            <ATTRNAME><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRNAME>
            <ATTRVAL><![CDATA[example]]></ATTRVAL>
        </ATTRIBUTE>
        </ATTRIBUTELIST>
        <IMAGELIST>
            <IMGFILE><![CDATA[exampleLink.jpg]]></IMGFILE>
        </IMAGELIST>
    </ITEM>";

var list = new List<InsertClassDTO>();

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml); // LoadXml() is used to load XML from a string. Use Load() to load XML from a file path)

XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//ITEM[@CATEGORYID=10]");

foreach (XmlNode item in nodeList)
{
    //.... tranfert into DTO, then into list, and finally insert into DB for every iteration
    var attirbutes = new List<Attirbute>();

    foreach (XmlNode x in item["ATTRIBUTELIST"].SelectNodes("ATTRIBUTE/ATTRID[text() = 'prezzo'] | ATTRIBUTE/ATTRID[text() = 'telagenzia']"))
    {
        attirbutes.Add(new Attirbute()
        {
            Id = x.ParentNode["ATTRID"].InnerText,
            Value = x.ParentNode["ATTRVAL"].InnerText,
        });
    }

    list.Add(new InsertClassDTO()
    {
        Email = item["EMAIL"].InnerText,
        Attributes = attirbutes
    });
}
```

You will also need some models:

```
public class InsertClassDTO
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<Attirbute> Attributes { get; set; }


}
public class Attirbute
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it definitly work (even if i had to use .Load becouse the .LoadXml() give me an exception, dunno rly why). The only problem is that i dont need all the attributes from this xml, but only someone, as "prezzo"(CDATA value) or telagenzia(always CDATA value)

Comment: I've updated the answer, so that the attributes only include values where ID = prezzo or telagenzia

Comment: sorry again, but what about if i want to get the value of the "ITEM" attributes (like "LASTUPDATE" or "EXPIRED") after i got the nodeList.
P.S. i dont need the combo between the ATTRID and ATTRVALUE, so i can only get the value i need using the position, is it correct?

Comment: try `item.Attributes["LASTUPDATE"].InnerText`